# How can I decide which service implementation to inject on a per request basis with Autofac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I'm using ASP.NET Web API/Autofac. Is there a way to decide which of two possible named services to inject on a per request basis depending on either route or query string parameter?

My registration looks like this:

```
var configuration = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

builder.RegisterType<Provider1>().Named<IProvider>("one").InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<Provider2>().Named<IProvider>("two").InstancePerRequest();

var container = builder.Build();
var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;
```

And my controller:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IProvider _provider;

    public SomeController(IProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }

    // GET /api/some?provider=x
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string provider)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by registering a lambda expression.

```
builder.Register(c => 
{
    if(true) 
    {
        return c.ResolveNamed<IProvider>("one");
    }
    else 
    {
        return c.ResolveNamed<IProvider>("two");
    }
})
.As<IProvider>()
.InstancePerRequest();
```

You can go further by creating a custom interface. For example, if you want to inject different implementation base on the site name, you can create a `ISiteNameProvider` interface. For example :

```
public interface ISiteNameProvider
{
    String SiteName { get; }
}

public class HttpContextSiteNameProvider : ISiteNameProvider
{
    public HttpContextSiteNameProvider(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        this._context = context;
    }

    private readonly HttpContextBase _context; 

    public String SiteName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._context.Request.Url.Host;
        }
    }
}
```

then

```
builder.RegisterType<HttpContextSiteNameProvider>()
       .As<ISiteNameProvider>()
       .InstancePerRequest();

builder.Register(c => 
{
    String siteName = c.Resolve<ISiteNameProvider>().SiteName;
    if(siteName == "www.domain.com") 
    {
        return c.ResolveNamed<IProvider>("one");
    }
    else 
    {
        return c.ResolveNamed<IProvider>("two");
    }
})
.As<IProvider>()
.InstancePerRequest();
```

Comment: This is cool stuff, but as I've implemented is the registrations happen at application startup and at that point I still don't know which of the two I'll need. Do I need to rethink? The first attempt I made I left the container as a public prop on my static bootstrap class and I could use 

var prov = Bootstrap.Container.ResolveNamed<IProvider>("one"); 

in the controller but that of course won't lend itself to DI at all.

Comment: > "the registrations happen at application startup". This is normal and my solution doesn't run during the registration process. I register a lambda which is executed when the application needs it. Looks at my second solution, the `SiteName` property is invoked each time a `IProvider` is requested.

Comment: Thank you. Just realized that. Though I have issues with the HttpContextBase argument. I added ".WithParameter("context", new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current))" to the registration of the version of the SiteNameProvider. Problem is my HttpContextBase.Current.Url contains neither the controller name nor the query. Also it's reporting a GET while I'm actually doing a POST. I suppose I've got to supply the context in some other way.

Comment: You should not use the `WithParameter` method to injection `HttpContextBase` did you use `builder.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();` ? it should do everything for you. See http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html for more information